# Deploy to Vercel, home page works but links do not

Tags: reactjs, express, vercel

I have an app using express on the backend and react on the front also using graphql.  It works on heroku but they are getting rid of the free tier so I'm trying to deploy to vercel.  The home page work find but if I click on any links I get a 404 error.  The site structure is:

The front end is in the 'client' folder and the backend is in the 'server' folder.

Here is the server/server.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const { ApolloServer } = require('apollo-server-express');
const path = require('path');

const { typeDefs, resolvers } = require('./schemas');
const db = require('./config/connection');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
const app = express();
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
});

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build')));
}

app.get('*', function (_, res) {
  res.sendFile(
    path.join(__dirname, '../client/build/index.html'),
    function (err) {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err);
      }
    }
  );
});


// Create a new instance of an Apollo server with the Graphql schema
const startApolloServer = async (typeDefs, resolvers) => {
  await server.start();
  server.applyMiddleware({ app });

  db.once('open', () => {
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log(`API server running on port ${PORT}!`);
      console.log(
        `Use GraphQL at http://localhost:${PORT}${server.graphqlPath}`
      );
    });
  });
};

// Call the asyn funcion to start the server
startApolloServer(typeDefs, resolvers);
```

Here is the client/src/app.js file:

```
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/client';
import { Route, Routes, BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import About from './pages/About';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Test from './pages/Test';

// Construct our main GraphQL API endpoint
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: '/graphql',
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

function App() {
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <Router>
        <Header />
        <main>
          <Routes>
            <Route path='/' element={<Home />}>
              Home
            </Route>
            <Route path='/about' element={<About />}>
              About
            </Route>
            <Route path='/test' element={<Test />}>
              Test
            </Route>
          </Routes>
        </main>
      </Router>
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```